# SQL - Replace column value is not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Initially the website is built with wordpress. The domain got changed from `https://olddomain.com` to `https://newdomain.com` and I have to migrate  to DB as well.

In the Post content there is image `url` like

- `https://olddomain.com/wp-content/upload/2023/01/imagename.png`
- `https://olddomain.com/wp-content/upload/xxxx/xx/imagename.png` **etc**.

what i want to achieve is replace `https://olddomain.com/wp-content/upload/2023/01/imagename.png` with `https://newdomain.com/public/media/images/imagename.png`

I tried by using `REPLACE` via sql query as following:

```sql
Update  posts
Set post_description = replace(post_description, 'https://olddomain.com/wp-content/upload/', 'https://newdomain.com/public/media/images/')
```

The `https://olddomain.com/wp-content/upload/xxxx/xx/imagename.png` has become `https://newdomain.com/public/media/images/xxx/xx/imagename.png`

Now the challenge is replacing /xxxx/xx with ''.
Is it possible with SQL replace or what could be alternate solution.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql should be able to give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this mysql query:

```
UPDATE posts
SET post_description = REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        post_description, 
        'https://olddomain.com/wp-content/upload/', 
        'https://newdomain.com/public/media/images/'
    ), 
    SUBSTRING(post_description, LOCATE('https://olddomain.com/wp-content/upload/', post_description) + LENGTH('https://olddomain.com/wp-content/upload/'), 8),
    ''
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example query that should work:

```
UPDATE posts
SET post_description = REPLACE(post_description,
'https://olddomain.com/wp-content/uploads/',
'https://newdomain.com/public/media/images/')
, post_description = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_description, '/', -3),
'/',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_description, '/', -1))
WHERE post_description LIKE '%https://olddomain.com/wp-content/uploads/%';
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it doesn't working, I have to run just replace image url, rest of the content will remain same.